# alarm is automatic running after reboot even alarm is not set android

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-reboot

Hi I am developing an application in Android which playing Alarm. It can reset alarm after reboot phone . But there is a problem that, it is running alarm even if alarm is not set at all. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should check you if your 'if' statement is correct before your instruction is running, or if you don't have register 'ON_BOOT_RECEIVER' broadcast in your manifest.

Anothor solution is to debug your code with System.out.println() to check each variable state, or each step.

Comment: I have already registered BOOT_RECEIVED broadcast in Manifest.xml that's why its running Alarm after reboot. But its also running even alarm is not set.

Comment: Just set a condition in your broadcastReceiver to check if alarm is set or not before playing it.

Comment: can you please explore it, how to do that??